# Why my JavaScript 2D array is being sorted when pushing a new element?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm writing a function that takes a given word as a parameter and returns its characters' position based on this 2D array:

```js
let keyboard = [
  ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "1", "2", "3"],
  ["f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "4", "5", "6"],
  ["k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "7", "8", "9"],
  ["p", "q", "r", "s", "t", ".", "@", "0"],
  ["u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "_", "/"],
];

function tvRemote(word) {
  let arr = [...word];
  let position = [];
  for (let rows = 0; rows < keyboard.length; rows++) {
    for (let cols = 0; cols < keyboard[rows].length; cols++) {
      for (i of arr) {
        keyboard[rows][cols] === i ? position.push([i, rows, cols]) : null;
      }
    }
  }
  return position;
}
console.log( tvRemote("your") );
```

I'd like to get the position in order to perform some calculations, but when pushing the rows and cols to the position array, the return seems to get sorted.

Expected output:

```
[ [ 'y', 4, 4 ], [ 'o', 2, 4 ], [ 'u', 4, 0 ], [ 'r', 3, 2 ] ]
```

What I'm getting:

```
[ [ 'o', 2, 4 ], [ 'r', 3, 2 ], [ 'u', 4, 0 ], [ 'y', 4, 4 ] ]
```

Does anyone know what's going on? and if so, how can I prevent that auto sort?

Comment: um, you are not going in order of your word, you are going by the order of the arrays So it is not sorting.... your logic is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're iterating in the order of rows and columns, not in order of the letters.

Read through your code carefully; first you set `rows = 0`, then `cols = 0`, then you iterate over `arr`. For the first case, you will be looking at `keyboard[0][0]` and checking to see if it matches any letters in `arr`, then if it does, pushing it to `position`. If nothing matches, you're moving to the next column, then eventually the next row.

Instead, you need to iterate in the order of the letters in `arr`, like so:

```js
function tvRemote(word) {
  let arr = [...word];
  let position = [];
  for (i of arr) {
    for (let rows = 0; rows < keyboard.length; rows++) {
      for (let cols = 0; cols < keyboard[rows].length; cols++) {
        keyboard[rows][cols] === i ? position.push([i, rows, cols]) : null;
      }
    }
  }
  return position;

tvRemote("your");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could move the word iteration to top to get the wanted order.

A slightly better approach is to continue the outer loop on find.

```js
function tvRemote(word) {
  let arr = [...word];
  let position = [];
  outer: for (i of arr) {
    for (let rows = 0; rows < keyboard.length; rows++) {
      for (let cols = 0; cols < keyboard[rows].length; cols++) {
        if (keyboard[rows][cols] === i) {
          position.push([i, rows, cols]);
          continue outer;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return position;
}

let keyboard = [["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "1", "2", "3"], ["f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "4", "5", "6"], ["k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "7", "8", "9"], ["p", "q", "r", "s", "t", ".", "@", "0"], ["u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "_", "/"]];

console.log(tvRemote("your"));
```

A fast approach by collecting all indices in an object and map just the wanted word.

```js
function tvRemote(word) {
    return Array.from(
        word,
        l => positions[l]
    );
}

let keyboard = [["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "1", "2", "3"], ["f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "4", "5", "6"], ["k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "7", "8", "9"], ["p", "q", "r", "s", "t", ".", "@", "0"], ["u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "_", "/"]],
    positions = keyboard.reduce((r, a, i) => {
        a.forEach((l, j) => r[l] = [l, i, j]);
        return r;
    }, {})

console.log(tvRemote("your"));
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you for answering, although I don't fully understand the fast approach, moving the word iteration to the top solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your loops are working on the matrix first and then searching in your word. Since your matrix is in alphabetical order that is why you face this.

Besides the fact that you need to move your word loop at the top level, you also do not need to use the `spread` operator. [for of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) can iterate on strings.

```
function tvRemote(word) {
  let position = [];
     for (let i of word) {
  for (let rows = 0; rows < keyboard.length; rows++) {
    for (let cols = 0; cols < keyboard[rows].length; cols++) {
 
        keyboard[rows][cols] === i ? position.push([i, rows, cols]) : null;
      }
    }
  }

  return position;
}
```

Comment: I just discovered the for of, thanks for letting me know that it can iterate on strings!